# C# console move in array

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I'm creating a small console game where player moves an array of objects and he must get to princess. I want the elements of array to be places, so I have classes such as desert, forest, cave and lake, so array must consist of this objects. each of this places do random damage or heals player. Any ideas how to make player move with wasd from the starting position of array to the princess

I want array to look like this:

```
PLAYER  lake      forest  lake
desert  forest    lake    desert
cave    PRINCESS  lake    forest
```

I'm handling with keys with consolekey. And key and I'm using switch case for this

```
while ((keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.X)
{
    switch (keyinfo.Key)
    {
        case Console.Key.W
        break;
        case Console.Key.A
        break;
        case Console.Key.S
        break;
        case Console.Key.D
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is my interface:

```
interface IPlace
{
    string PlaceName { get; }
    int randomPdamage();
    int randomPgiveHp();
}
```

I have four places: lake, forest, cave, desert each of them implements the `IPlace` interface:

```
class Forest : IPlace
{
    public string PlaceName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Forest";
        }
    }

    Random DmgAndHeal = new Random();

    public int randomPdamage()
    {
        int PlaceDamage = DmgAndHeal.Next(5, 20);
        return PlaceDamage;
    }

    public int randomPgiveHp()
    {

        int PlaceHeal = DmgAndHeal.Next(5, 20);
        return PlaceHeal;
    }
}
```

This is my main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        IPlace desert = new Desert();
        IPlace lake = new Lake();
        IPlace cave = new Cave();
        IPlace forest = new Forest();

        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;

        String[,] values = new string[3, 5] { { "lake", "lake" , "cave" , "forest" , "lake"  },
                                              { "desert" , "forest" , "cave ", "lake" , "desert"  },
                                              { "cave" , "desert", "forest", "lake" , "desert" }}; 

        for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < values.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                Console.Write(values[i, k]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        while ((keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.X)
        {
            switch (keyInfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.W:
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.D:
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.S:
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.A:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Provide an example with what you tried already and write down a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that keeping player in same array with map is good idea, because in that case after player leave some cell you don't have information about what should be in this cell (lake, cave, desert etc.)

My suggestion would be:

1. Store objects that unable to move in the array like:

   forest  lake      forest  lake
   desert  forest    lake    desert
   cave    lake  lake    forest
2. Store coordinates of moving objects, like player, for example:

   int playerX = 0;
   int playerY = 0;

Or make it properties of player object.

3. When you drawing your screen check if player coordinates mach with current cell and if it does draw player instead

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
       {
           for (int k = 0; k < map.GetLength(1); k++)
           {
               if (playerX == k && playerY == i)
                   DrawPlayer();
               else
                   DrawCell(map[i,k]);
           }
       }
   ```

In that way to move player you just need to change it's X or Y position.

**Edit:** after apply this to your code you should get something like this:

```
    int playerX = 0; //horizontal coordinate
    int playerY = 0; //vertical coordinate
    ConsoleKey key = ConsoleKey.Separator; //filled with meanless value by default
    do
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.W:
                if (playerY > 0) //check that player will't leave field
                    playerY--;   //change player position
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D:
                if (playerX < values.GetLength(1) - 1)
                    playerX++;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.S:
                if (playerY < values.GetLength(0) - 1)
                    playerY++;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.A:
                if (playerX > 0)
                    playerX--;
                break;
        }

        Console.Clear(); //clear console to redraw field

        for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < values.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                if (i == playerY && k == playerX) //check if player in cell [i,k]
                    Console.Write("Player\t"); //draw player
                else
                    Console.Write(values[i, k] + "\t"); //draw place
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key; //read new key
    }
    while (key != ConsoleKey.X); //exit condition
```

**P. S. You can test this code here: [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMY2JKRmtSZ0NxaUk)**

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're asking about the way you can  manipulate already written text in the console window. Than the basic technique is the following:

1. Place the cursor on the position where you need by using Console
   properties: Console.CursorTop and Console.CursorLeft which just mean
   the line and column in the console where to place cursor.
2. Write to console using Console.Write
3. If you want to move the Player - just use Console.MoveBufferArea which move the block of text in the console from specified place to   the target position.
4. After that you need to get back to the previous player position and restore existing place value(forest, river etc).